# IllegalAccessException myfaces appengine 1.8.1

Tags: java, google-app-engine, myfaces

jdk 1.7
gae 1.8.1
myfaces 2.1.11

my app was working fine with gae 1.8.0.

i just updated to appengine sdk1.8.1 and i get the following exception, when running on local environment.

However the deployed environment seems to be ok.

```
SEVERE: Could not access AddResource class
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class com.google.appengine.tools.development.a
gent.runtime.Runtime can not access a member of class org.apache.myfaces.renderk
it.html.util.DefaultAddResource with modifiers "protected"
<snip>
at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.newInsta nce(Runtime.java:148)
at org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.util.AddResourceFactory.getInstance (AddResourceFactory.java:213)
at org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.util.AddResourceFactory.getInstance (AddResourceFactory.java:304)
```

why is the gae sdk 1.8.1 runtime checking suddenly not liking the DefaultAddResource class?

looks like it is a jdk issue. when i switch back to the windows jdk 1.6 everything is ok.

any help welcomed

-lp

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I was using jdk 1.7.0_25 and gae 1.8.7
At last I fixed the problem by switching to jdk 1.6.0_35  and gae 1.8.4. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk6u35-downloads-1836443.html